# Mapping Excel Column based on Specific String (Using Python)

Tags: python, pandas

There is 2 different Column.

Column 1:
123_Car_Red,
124_Truck_Red,
125_Helicopter_Red

Column 2:
Helicopter,
Car,
Truck,

I want to create a new Column (Column 3) that will look for similarity from Column 2 with Column 1
and print Column 2 value based on Column 1 value order.

Example:

Column 1:
123_Car_Red,
124_Truck_Red,
125_Helicopter_Red

Column 2:
Helicopter,
Car,
Truck,

**Column 3:
Car,
Truck,
Helicopter**

Comment: why do you call them columns? Does `123_Car_Red` have anything to do with `Helicopter`, for instance?

Comment: What is your question?  What have you tried so far?  This isn't a code writing service.  "write this code for me" is not a valid question here.  You need to take a stab at this yourself, and then post the code that you are having problems with when you get stuck.  If you can't get started, then you might want to google for a basic tutorial on manipulating 2D numeric data structures.  Check out [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Follow some of the tutorials for it.